# Excel VBA function to make a cell text 'BOLD' won't work

Tags: vba, excel

```
Public Function highlight_text(Search)
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  Set rng = Range("A2:H32")

  For Each cell In rng
      If cell.text = Search Then
          cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
          cell.Font.Name = "Arial"
          cell.Font.Size = 14
          cell.Font.Bold = True
      Else
          cell.Font.Bold = False
          cell.Font.Size = 11
          cell.Font.ColorIndex = 1
      End If
  Next cell
End Function
```

The above function is called on 'mouseover' a cell, it manages to set the proper cells to RED color but it won't make the text bold

Comment: It works for me.

Comment: @ScottCraner - Really? It doesn't for me.  I have the function in a workbook module. It makes it red, but no bold.

Comment: it is bold, the red makes it hard to see, but according to excel it is bold.

Comment: @BruceWayne see: https://imgur.com/cQwtqdL  You can clearly see the `B` in the tool bar is selected.

Comment: @ScottCraner - [uhhhhhh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CSMz5.gif)...Huh?  I'm calling it via worksheet. Maybe that's it?  Edit: Yep, that's it. If I call via a sub `Sub whatever() // highlight_text "not bold :(" // End Sub`  it correctly bolds it.  Now I wonder why it matters to VBA *how* it's called...it's still running the same script.

Comment: You can't call it from a worksheet function.  It needs to be called by a sub @BruceWayne

Comment: I am surprised it even does the coloring through the worksheet call. @BruceWayne  I did not think it possible to change any part of the format of another cell that way.

Comment: It was working for me

Comment: Is there any way to make it work if i call it from the worksheet ? and what do you meab by calling it via a sub ?

Comment: no, there is no way. Imagine you have two cells with this function, one looking for one word and the other for another.  which one wins out?  That is why it should not be possible to change the format of cell via the worksheet.

Comment: @NetaMeta use a Worksheet_SelectionChange event to call the function.

Comment: @ScottCraner - I notice also, if you take the `Bold` part out of a function and put it in a sub, and call it from the function, you *still* can't bold it calling that original function from the worksheet.  Didn't realize any of that before. Nice to know!

Comment: Scott post this as an answer so i can accept it

Comment: @ScottCraner LOL - I was just playing and set the formula in J2 to be `=highlight_text("TEST1")+J3` and then put the formula `=highlight_text("TEST2")` into J3 - it very quickly coloured all the "TEST2" values then uncoloured them and coloured the "TEST1" values (because it was evaluated last).  This could get interesting!!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot call a function from the worksheet and change the format of a cell.

(The fact that even the color is changing is perplexing)

As this does not need to be a function, it does not return anything and you cannot use it from the worksheet, we can make it a sub:

```
Public Sub highlight_text(Search)
  Dim rng As Range
  Dim cell As Range
  Set rng = Range("A2:H32")

  For Each cell In rng
      If cell.Text = Search Then
          cell.Font.ColorIndex = 3
          cell.Font.Name = "Arial"
          cell.Font.Size = 14
          cell.Font.Bold = True
      Else
          cell.Font.Bold = False
          cell.Font.Size = 11
          cell.Font.ColorIndex = 1
      End If
  Next cell
End Sub
```

Use a Worksheet_Change Event(or some other event) to call the sub:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
If Not Intersect(Target, Range("A2:H32")) Is Nothing Then
    highlight_text (Target.Text)
End If
End Sub
```

Put both of these in the worksheet code in which you want the code to run.

This will now highlight the like cells as you click on any cell in the range.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

This is a good solution in this case. But I am confused by the statement that you cannot change to format of a cell in a function. Tried this to confirm. It works fine.

```
Function boldit() As String
Dim theCell As String  

theCell = "Q8"
Range(theCell).Value = "XorY"
Range(theCell).Font.Color = RGB(255, 0, 0)
Range(theCell).Font.Bold = True

End Function
```

The reason I'm interested is that in a real function I have written the same .Font.Bold statement does not work (while the .Font.Color does)
Any other idea why .Font.Bold=True might not work

Comment: After further testing, I see that this will actually not work if the function is called from the worksheet.