# Format cell as BOLD

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a function that returns a BOLD format of a cell?

This is my code but it says Invalid Qualifier

```
    Function Bold(Text As String) As String
    
       Text.Font.Bold = True
    
       Bold = Text
    
    End Function
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Functions return values, not formats.

Comment: And String is a data type, it doesn't have properties.

Answer (score 1):

You could use [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.font.bold) instead of creating a function?

Comment: I want to use function though. is there a way to do it this way?

Comment: So I just have to call the function =Bold( "Target Cell")

Comment: @BarhomIbrahim You can lookup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46353336/excel-vba-function-to-make-a-cell-text-bold-wont-work)